# Is there a way to allow only one Type as Attribute in Java?

Tags: java, types, static, attributes

I have a class and I only want multiple static attributes of the dype `Pair<Integer, String>` in this class. Not more. Is there a way I can define a superclass or something else that there is no way to add another variable attribute.

It so important that I have multiple attributes and not for example a list or enum.

Example:

```
public class Test {

  public static final Pair<Integer, String> a ...

  public static final Pair<Integer, String> b ...

  public static final Pair<Integer, String> c ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to limit what static fields any given class may declare by making superclasses or superinterfaces. The only thing that could do it, is an Annotation Processor (even if you use no annotations). However, there isn't a way to enforce the person doing the compilation to run that processor.

If you're interested in this: It is not easy, and explaining how to do this would be an order of magnitude beyond the reasonable scope of an SO question. Search the web for tutorials on Annotation Processors.